# How to reference two assemblies in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have two assemblies: Assembly-CSharp and Assembly-CSharp-Editor.

Example: https://ibb.co/Phy8Y7S - Structure of my project

I have the following error: https://ibb.co/jgwzYmx - The error

ThirdPersonController.cs is in the first assembly Assembly-CSharp. But I get an error.

Why? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Do you have the correct using statement in your file?

Comment: Yea. But i get error. It's something like missing refernce but I reference Assembly-CSharp-Editor to  Assembly-CSharp.

Comment: In the second assembly, go to project, Add Reference. After that, try `CTRL + .` on the class with the squiggles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press `Alt + Enter` or `Ctrl + .` Visual Studio should be smart enough to automatically add a reference from the one project to the other or import the correct using statement if such is omitted.

Comment: Can you look at this: https://ibb.co/RPNjjpx
https://ibb.co/S3xJ4c8

Comment: And the solution should be the same as well. I am not sure but you may have some circular dependencies in those two projects so can you send me a screenshot of all the references for the two projects?

Comment: What is the name of the class at Screenshot 9?

Comment: CullingFadeControlEditor. But in my code the custom editor is from type CullingFadeControl.cs which is in the first assembly. CullingFadeControlEditor is in the second.

Comment: Hmmm, it looks all good. I would try again and again to spam those key combination until VS decides to do the right thing.

Comment: Other reason for that issue may be if those two classes have some namespace conflicts that should be resolved with the `global::` directive.

Comment: Your screenshots aren't showing that the assemblies are missing. It is possible they're older builds of the assembly and the build order of the solution is not building them in the correct order. Try building your projects individually by right-clicking each one and selecting "Build".

Comment: https://ibb.co/2gTMSt7
https://ibb.co/F4hppWh. As I said CullingFadeControlEditor is in Assembly-CSharp-Editor without namespace. And CullingFadeControl is in Assembly-CSharp and is with namespace TheAncientTribe. I have ReSharper and when I press Alt + Enter nothing happens.

Comment: Why do not you try to manually write down the using statement? It would be something like `using TheancientTribe;` and lets see if that should solve the problem.